# How to do Damage During Animation When Enemy Enters Range?

Tags: unity-game-engine

2D Top Down style game. I’m trying to figure out how to hit an enemy whenever he enters the range of my attack point and get hit every, say, 3 frames if he is still within my attack point. here's my script.

```
 public Animator animator;

public Transform AttackPoint;

public float attackRange = 0.5f;

public LayerMask enemyLayers;

public int attackDamage = 40;

public float attackRate = 1f;
float nextAttackTime = 0f;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if(Time.time >= nextAttackTime)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Attack();
            nextAttackTime = Time.time + 1f / attackRate;
        }
    }
}

void Attack()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("Attack");
    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackPoint.position, attackRange, enemyLayers);
    foreach(Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        enemy.GetComponent<Enemy>().TakeDamage(attackDamage);
    }
}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    if (AttackPoint == null)
        return;

    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(AttackPoint.position, attackRange);
}
```

Comment: so what's problem in this ?

Comment: The enemy only get damaged on key press, not constantly while inside the attack point. My skill is continuous so I need to be able to damage the enemy anytime he enters the attack point, not on key press alone.

Answer (score 0):

foreach enemys and check distance with you , and attack it.
and you need a Manager to handle all enemys.

```
List<Transform> enemys = new List<Transform>();
public void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < enemys.Count; i++)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(enemys[i].position, transform.position);
        if (distance < 10)// in range
        {
            //todo attack
        }
    }
}
```